# jQuery Templates are they part of the core jQuery library?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I'm reading this in a previous Scott Guthrie blog (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/04/jquery-templates-data-link-and-globalization-accepted-as-official-jquery-plugins.aspx)

"in the next major release of jQuery (jQuery 1.5), the jQuery Templates plugin will be included as a standard part of the core jQuery library."

Did this happen e.g. are they part of the core library?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2011/04/15/update-on-the-microsoft-jquery-plugins.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No they're not**, but are easily accessible from jQuery's documentation page links:

- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js

Or you can as well watch the project [on GitHub](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl).

They're also quite well documented on the [jQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) where every other aspect of jQuery's documented. There are actually only two such plugins there:

- jQuery Templates plugin and
- jQuery Data Link plugin

Unfortunately Globalization plugin had no such luck to be included in official jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No, as of now they aren't.  It appears to still be in the beta1 version: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Answer (score 0):

No it didn't get included as a part of the core, however, you just have to include http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js to use it.